# Задача на нахождение самого короткого слова в тексте.

Tags: delphi, алгоритм

Найти самое короткое слово в веденной пользователем  строке (на делфипаскале).

Comment: фи, как банально

@BenderT, попробуйте сами, что не получится - помогу. За вас писать никто не будет.

Comment: Да, банально, но блин, именно этот пример что-то не получился, хотя, что самое смешное-намного более сложные примеры(в том числе сложные из ООП) получились правильно)))

Answer (score 5):

Получаем строку.

Заводим четыре переменные:

1. Счетчик — длина текущего слова;
2. Позиция начала текущего слова;
3. Длина самого короткого встреченного слова;
4. Позиция начала самого короткого встреченного слова.

Начинаем в цикле проходить строку посимвольно. Для кодировок с фиксированной длиной символа (а-ля CP1251, CP866 или ISO-8859-1) все просто, для кодировок с переменной длиной символа (например, UTF-8) — нужно хитрее. Школоте и непрофильным и/или молодым студентам, как правило, про эти сложности на рассказывают, так что если нет понимания о чем тут речь — можно абзац проигнорировать. Пока.

Если очередной символ — литера (буква или другой, входящий в «слово» символ), то:

- Если счетчик длины текущего слова был 0 (нет текущего слова), то запоминаем позицию.
- Делаем +1 к длине текущего слова.

Если не литера:

- Если длина текущего слова больше 0 (т.е. было что-то), то сравниваем с длиной самого короткого встреченного слова.
- Нашли короче? Запоминаем длину и позицию.
- Сбрасываем длину текущего слова в 0.

Так гоняем до конца строки или до нахождения слова в 1 символ (т.е. дальше искать смысла нет).

Дальше дело техники — положение в строке мы знаем, длину слова (или факт того, что слов в строке не было) — знаем.

Никаких масивов и прочего цирка здесь не нужно. Можно, но не нужно. Тупой конечный автомат, поиск в один проход, за `O(n)`.

Вот вся основная идея. Код — извольте писать сами, в конце-концов это Ваше задание. Если что-то непонятно — спрашивайте конкретные вопросы (и то, как Вы пытались их решать).

Comment: Каюсь, плюсик) Тут уже подумать надо было)

Comment: Ну, уж заодно к такому обстоятельному описанию, намекнули бы для новичков, как взглянув на первый байтик UTF-8 вычислить сколько байт занимает этот символ (следовательно, на сколько байт смещаться дальше).

Comment: Ну, если на пальцах, то для UTF-8 правило простое — посчитать сколько старших единичных бит. Сколько бит, столько байт и занимает символ, за исключением, что если старший бит нулевой — то символ занимает один (этот) байт.

Т.е. если первый байт, скажем, `0xC2` = `0b`*`11`*`000010`, то и символ занимает 2 байта (т.е. дальше еще один).

Алгоритмов парсинга UTF-8 в сети куча.

Comment: Если считать, что utf не битый, то читать все байты внутри utf-символа не надо, т.к. в символах пунктуации (а также цифрах и т.п.) старший бит - 0. Хотя, все зависит от правил, какой символ часть слова.

Comment: Если старший бит нулевой, то мы весь символ и прочитали, пропускать-то нечего ;)

А дальше — если уж говорить про Unicode — то и делать по-человечески, используя [Unicode Character Database](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/). Видимо, не руками (слишком неблагодарное занятие), но я совершенно не в курсе как в Delphi кошерно работать с libicu.

Answer (score 0):

Я, конечно, в Delphi не силён, но это основы! Хотите достигнуть результата - зазубривайте основы. Синтаксис языка не так важен. 
Суть в следующем: заранее нельзя предугадать, что именно введёт пользователь. Он может создать строку только из одного слова. А может и четыре попробовать набрать.
Строка - это, в любом случае, массив символов. Рассмотрим понятие "слово" в контексте компилятора: слово - это последовательность символов, разделенная пробелами. Это мы, люди, принимаем слова как нечто осмысленное, что позволяет нам выражать свои мысли. Однако, для компьютерной техники это не так. Приведу пример: `рпавол вфушщо мтвлопопра`. Если взять грубо - это строка из трёх слов и не важно, что они не несут смысла.

Ну вот у нас и возникает уже понимание сути задачи. Заводим два счётчика: один для определения непрерывной череды символов (длины слова по-другому), другой - для запоминания номера самого длинного слова. Вот и всё. Берём массив этих символов (строку, введённую пользователем) и проходим циклом. Подсчитываем количество символов, отличных от пробела, встретили пробел - сохраняем количество в переменной массива, в котором хранятся длины слов и т.д.
На выходе получаем массив, в котором находятся длины слов, из них надо найти максимальное и вывести на экран. Ну а с выводом номера самого длинного слова, я думаю, уже проблем не возникнет.

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм примерно такой (очень простой, можно конечно оптимизмровать):

1. Присваиваем предложение строковой переменной.
2. Разбиваем предложение на слова и храним в массиве. Например, по пробелу, запятой и т.д.
3. Заводим переменную и присваиваем ей длину первого слова (`minLenght`, например). Также заводим переменную для хранения индекса.
4. Потом в цикле пробегаем по массиву слов и сравниваем длину слова с переменной, которую мы завели (`minLength`). Если длина меньше, то присваиваем этой переменной длину текущего слова.
5. Выводим самое маленькое слово, длину знаем  и индекс в массиве знаем.

Comment: Зачем разбивать и создавать копию в массиве? Лишней памяти позанимать? Тут нужен, по сути, простейший конечный автомат, проходящий по строке посимвольно.

Comment: Задача тривиальная, но если автор задает, то у него не очень глубокие познания пока, поэтому решил написать так. Если автор напишет хотя бы такой вариант (сам), то в дальнейшем он уже сможет сам оптимизировать решение, задумается о памяти и другом.

Comment: по памяти можно вместиться так:

    var userString, minWord: string;
        pos, wordStart: integer;
        readingWord: boolean;

@sharok, на массив разбивать сложнее)

Comment: @Sh4dow: `minWord` — некрасиво. Опять же, лишние копирования пока не найдем действительно самое короткое слово.

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение этой задачи с использованием ООП:

```
program Project3; {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  Classes;
type
  TLst = class(TStringList)
    function CompareStrings(const a,b: string): integer; override;
  end;
  function TLst.CompareStrings;
  begin
    Result := Length(a)-Length(b);
    if Result = 0 then
      Result := inherited CompareStrings(a,b)
  end;
var
  s : string;
begin
  with TLst.Create do
    try Sorted := true;
      repeat ReadLn(s);
        DelimitedText := s;
        if Count > 0 then
          WriteLn('<',Strings[0],'>')
      until s = ''
    finally Free end
end.
```

Причем, обрабатывается произвольное количество строк (в цикле repeat ReadLn(s) пока не будет введена пустая строка - until s = '').
Таким образом, основное тело цикла Repeat состоит всего из двух операторов:

```
DelimitedText := s;  // - очередную строку разбить на слова и отсортировать
WriteLn(Strings[0]); // - верхний элемент получившегося списка и есть ответ
```

Где предваряющий вывод оператрор ***if Count > 0 then ...*** - *"защита"* от пустого списка.

То, что разбиваемый список слов будет сортируемым, задается назначением свойства ***Sorted := true***, а правильность сортировки для нашей задачи устанавливается переопределением функции ***CompareStrings*** (в согласии с духом и буквой ООП) в наследнике ***TStringList***, взятым нами за основу:

*"...Халатик такой же, но пуговицы - перламутровые..." (с) к/ф Бриллиантовая рука.*

Следует отметить, что сортировка, задаваемая здесь используется даже более изощренная, чем указывалось в первоначальной задаче, так как там не указано, что же делать, если в исходной строке встретится несколько слов с минимальной длинной - кого выбрать? Поэтому здесь идет сортировка по двойному признаку: каждое сравнение идет вначале по длине слов, а затем, при равной длине - по алфавиту, т.е. используется традиционный лексикографический порядок (благодаря использованию ***inherited...***).

При желании, если необходимо различать буквы верхнего и нижнего регистра (по умолчанию - здесь не различаются), достаточно просто назначить соответствующее значение свойству ***CaseSensitive***.

Особо хочу отметить, что здесь используется анонимный список (разработанный нами при наследовании ***TStringList - TLst***) без использования переменной этого типа в ***var-секции*** и поэтому же (благодаря использованию оператора ***with***) все операторы внутри защищенного блока ***try-finally-end*** получаются короткими и наглядными, а сама программа - понятной, прозрачной и легко модифицируемой.

Comment: В результате имеем безбожно жрущую память и наверное самую медленную из программ, решающих ту же задачу.

Впрочем, похоже, адептов ООП это уже давно не волнует.

Comment: Покажешь класс? - свою альтернативную программу, которая также легко модифицируется под вновь возникающие обстоятельства в задаче и при этом не столь "...безбожно жрущую память..." и такую "...самую медленную из программ..."

Мы их сравним: посмотрим их размеры, потребляемую память и скорость выполнения. Прикинем, что мы приобретаем и что теряем и за какую цену, а потом сделаем выводы - насколько правы или не правы те, кто является "адептом ООП" и почему, возможно, это их не волнует...

Comment: Может быть цена вопроса - баланс потерь и выгод - сильно преувеличен в сторону потерь в головах некоторых "экспертов", а на деле всё совсем наоборот и, возможно, это объясняет факт мирового признания ООП-технологий?

Comment: По сути где-то так (на крестах)

    ifstream inpf(FILENAME);
    string s, w;
    size_t len = 0, curlen;
    
    while (getword(inpf, s)) {
      curlen = count_chars(s);
      if (!len || curlen > len) {
        w = s; len = curlen;
      }
    }

Остальное очевидно.

Comment: @avp

> В результате имеем безбожно жрущую память и наверное самую медленную из программ, решающих ту же задачу.
Впрочем, похоже, адептов ООП это уже давно не волнует.

-_-